# Routes ASP.NET desconfigurado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, route

De tanto tentar e fuçar eu acho que acabei desconfigurando alguma coisa importante, por isso não consigo fazer as rotas funcionarem.

Nesta imagem aparece que o form esta como post enviando para o controller LoginProfessional na action Logon. Eu não estou usando o RenderBody para carregar este form de login, a idéia é usar somente a action do controller sem precisar usar view, pois ela já esta no local correto

[image: Nesta imagem aparece que o form esta como post enviando para o controller LoginProfessional na action Logon. Eu não estou usando o RenderBody para carregar este form de login, a idéia é usar somente a action do controller sem precisar usar view, pois ela já esta no local correto.]

Aqui aparece que existe a Action Logon no controller LoginProfessional
[image: Aqui aparece que existe a Action Logon no controller LoginProfessional]

Aqui o erro e a URL
[image: Aqui o erro e a url]

Arquivo de Rotas, a página home do site entra normalmente, porém quero acessar o controller LoginProfessional e apos o login feito, redirecionar para dentro de uma Area.
[image]

Comment: Você mudou a rota? porque realmente ta errado !!! pelos desenhos, passe também na pergunta o arquivo de rotas [`RouteConfig`]. Pelo desenho ser ver o arquivo de rota seria `/Home/Logon`

Comment: Como está o método RegisterRoutes do seu arquivo Global.asax?

Comment: @FCCDias Editado com o print do RouteConfig....

Comment: @bigodera esta na versão original.

Comment: Foi o que eu disse a você é `/Home/Logon`, pelo menos pelas imagens ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `Controller` não é `/LoginProfissional/Logon`. É `/Home/Logon`.

Crie um `LoginProfissionalController` ou então use a rota `/Home/Logon`.

Comment: Já possuo este controller "LoginProfessionalController"

Comment: Pelas imagens, ele não está sendo usado. A implementação de `Logon` está no `HomeController`. Sendo assim, `/Home/Logon` funciona.

Comment: Em qual imagem vc ve isto? Pois aqui no projeto tem o "LoginProfessionalController"

Comment: Esta: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sa9hD.png. O método `Login` está no `HomeController`, e não no `LoginProfissionalController`, como deveria estar, pelo que você descreveu.

Comment: Tu é o cara! hehe funcionou mesmo, falta de atenção minha! Obrigado!